# Writing to eventfd from kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have created an eventfd instance in a userspace program using eventfd(). Is there a way in which I can pass some reference (a pointer to its struct or pid+fd pair) to this created instance of eventfd to a kernel module so that it can update the counter value?

Here is what I want to do:
I am developing a userspace program which needs to exchange data and signals with a kernel space module which I have written.
For transferring data, I am already using ioctl. But I want the kernel module to be able to signal the userspace program whenever new data is ready for it to consume over ioctl.

To do this, my userspace program will create a few eventfds in various threads. These threads will wait on these eventfds using select() and whenever the kernel module updates the counts on these eventfds, they will go on to consume the data by requesting for it over ioctl.

The problem is, how do I resolve the "struct file *" pointers to these eventfds from kernelspace? What kind of information bout the eventfds can I sent to kernel modules so that it can get the pointers to the eventfds? what functions would I use in the kernel module to get those pointers?

Is there better way to signal events to userspace from kernelspace?
I cannot let go of using select().

Comment: What I am trying to do is write my own protocol stack as a kernel module and I want to creat API similar to the socket functions provided by libc. I will use LD_PRELOAD to write my own version of socket(), connect(), recv() etc. Now all these functions operate on file descriptors and I want to preserve their argument and return types. My version of socket() would create an eventfd and return the descriptor to the userspace application. I need to tell the kernel module how to write to eventfd so that any waiting select() can return from it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this. I realized that each open file on a system could be identified by the pid of one of the processes which opened it and the fd corresponding to that file (within that process's context). So if my kernel module knows the pid and fd, it can look up the **struct * task_struct** of the process and from that the **struct * files** and finally using the fd, it can acquire the pointer to the eventfd's **struct * file**. Then, using this last pointer, it can write to the eventfd's counter.

Here are the codes for the userspace program and the kernel module that I wrote up to demonstrate the concept (which now work):

**Userspace C code (efd_us.c):**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>     //Definition of uint64_t
#include <sys/eventfd.h>

int efd; //Eventfd file descriptor
uint64_t eftd_ctr;

int retval;     //for select()
fd_set rfds;        //for select()

int s;

int main() {


    //Create eventfd
    efd = eventfd(0,0);
    if (efd == -1){
        printf("\nUnable to create eventfd! Exiting...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nefd=%d pid=%d",efd,getpid());

    //Watch efd
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(efd, &rfds);

    printf("\nNow waiting on select()...");
    fflush(stdout);

    retval = select(efd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (retval == -1){
        printf("\nselect() error. Exiting...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (retval > 0) {
        printf("\nselect() says data is available now. Exiting...");
        printf("\nreturned from select(), now executing read()...");
        s = read(efd, &eftd_ctr, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (s != sizeof(uint64_t)){
            printf("\neventfd read error. Exiting...");
        } else {
            printf("\nReturned from read(), value read = %lld",eftd_ctr);
        }
    } else if (retval == 0) {
        printf("\nselect() says that no data was available");
    }

    printf("\nClosing eventfd. Exiting...");
    close(efd);
    printf("\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Kernel Module C code (efd_lkm.c):**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/fdtable.h>
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>
#include <linux/eventfd.h>

//Received from userspace. Process ID and eventfd's File descriptor are enough to uniquely identify an eventfd object.
int pid;
int efd;

//Resolved references...
struct task_struct * userspace_task = NULL; //...to userspace program's task struct
struct file * efd_file = NULL;          //...to eventfd's file struct
struct eventfd_ctx * efd_ctx = NULL;        //...and finally to eventfd context

//Increment Counter by 1
static uint64_t plus_one = 1;

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Received from userspace: pid=%d efd=%d\n",pid,efd);

    userspace_task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Resolved pointer to the userspace program's task struct: %p\n",userspace_task);

    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Resolved pointer to the userspace program's files struct: %p\n",userspace_task->files);

    rcu_read_lock();
    efd_file = fcheck_files(userspace_task->files, efd);
    rcu_read_unlock();
    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Resolved pointer to the userspace program's eventfd's file struct: %p\n",efd_file);


    efd_ctx = eventfd_ctx_fileget(efd_file);
    if (!efd_ctx) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~eventfd_ctx_fileget() Jhol, Bye.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Resolved pointer to the userspace program's eventfd's context: %p\n",efd_ctx);

    eventfd_signal(efd_ctx, plus_one);

    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Incremented userspace program's eventfd's counter by 1\n");

    eventfd_ctx_put(efd_ctx);

    return 0;
}


void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "~~~Module Exiting...\n");
}  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_param(pid, int, 0);
module_param(efd, int, 0);
```

To run this, carry out the following steps:

1. Compile the userspace program (efd_us.out) and the kernel module (efd_lkm.ko)
2. Run the userspace program (./efd_us.out) and note the pid and efd values that it print. (for eg. "pid=2803 efd=3". The userspace program will wait endlessly on select()
3. Open a new terminal window and insert the kernel module passing the pid and efd as params: **sudo insmod efd_lkm.ko pid=2803 efd=3**
4. Switch back to the userspace program window and you will see that the userspace program has broken out of select and exited.

Comment: @lithiumhead Hi, Can you provide suggestions as to how send more data than just the plus_one counter to user space in an event ?

Comment: Actually that what I had set out to do. I am using ioctl to transfer big chunks of data (instead of just the plus_one) between userspace and kernel space. But I needed a way for kernel driver to tell the userspace program that my data was ready to be fetched via ioctl.

so you use eventfd along with ioctl. eventfd for signalling and ioctl for transferring data.

Comment: Most of kernel space lines can be replaced with "efd_ctx = eventfd_ctx_fdget(efd);"  No need to lookup the task, then files, then eventfd.

Answer (score 10):

Consult the kernel source here:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/eventfd.c

Basically, send your userspace file descriptor, as produced by `eventfd()`, to your module via `ioctl()` or some other path.  From the kernel, call `eventfd_ctx_fdget()` to get an eventfd context, then `eventfd_signal()` on the resulting context.  Don't forget `eventfd_ctx_put()` when you're done with the context.

Comment: Hi Peter,
Before I posted the question I did try what you are suggesting. Here are results: 
Step 1: I start a userspace program which creats and eventfd() and prints the value of the fd on screen before executing select() on it.
Step 2: In a separate terminal window I load a kernel module and pass the fd value (in my case it is 3 coz 0,1,2 correspond to stdin, stdout and stderr)
Step 3: The LKM tries to use eventfd_ctx_fdget() but returns an error. 

using lsof, I see that 3 is assigned to the eventfd but this "3" is not uniquely identified as different processes have open files with fds=3

Comment: @lithiumhead: Your kernel module needs to call `eventfd_ctx_fdget()` *in the context of the process*.  This is why Peter suggests passing it via `ioctl()` - the ioctl handler runs in the context of the process that called the `ioctl()`.

Comment: @caf: Hey thanks for that info, I have been wondering about that for the longest time now - i.e. how to do stuff inside the kernel while staying in the process's context! Knowing this will help me improve my ioctl operations!

Answer (score 1):

> how do I resolve the "struct file *" pointers to these eventfds from kernelspace

You must resolve those pointers into data structures that this interface you've created has published (create new types and read the fields you want from `struct file` into it).

> Is there better way to signal events to userspace from kernelspace?

[Netlink sockets](http://qos.ittc.ku.edu/netlink/html/) are another convenient way for the kernel to communicate with userspace.  "Better" is in the eye of the beholder.